# Oracle error - "Pending": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, double-quotes

i'm creating a query with typeorm with oracle.

I'm using this in a select, because the status can be null.

```
'NVL(Details.status, "Pending") AS "PostulationDetail_status"'
```

I have used this before but using 0, because i was working with numbers. I decided to test with strings and i got surprised. i get this error on console

```
[Nest] 620  - 18-11-2021 12:20:29   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ORA-00904: "Pending": invalid identifier
QueryFailedError: ORA-00904: "Pending": invalid identifier
```

I don't know how to write the query so it is valid. Does anyone had an experience like this ?

Comment: You put the hard-coded text `Pending` in **double** quotes, which makes it an identifier (column name, function name, etc.) in SQL. To indicate hard-coded text, use **single** quotes instead. Compare with what you put after the `AS` keyword - that is in double quotes, which is OK, because you are creating a column alias, not a text *value*.

Comment: Also: The error message says very clearly **"Pending": invalid identifier** - so why do you have **NVL invalid identifier** in your question's title? The error message doesn't complain about NVL, it complains about something else (and unrelated). Your title is misleading - before I even read the question, I had already started thinking about what might make NVL invalid, when in fact that has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: *I have used this before* - probably in MySQL or some other DB that plays fast n loose with " and ' for string delimiters ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use single quotes around string literals and either no quotes (the preferable, case-insensitive option) or double quotes (case-sensitive) around identifiers:

```sql
NVL(Details.status, 'Pending') AS "PostulationDetail_status"
```

If you use double quotes:

```sql
NVL(Details.status, "Pending") AS "PostulationDetail_status"
```

Then you are saying to return the `DETAILS.STATUS` value (this identifier is case-insensitive) or, if that is `NULL` then, use the value of the `Pending` column (this identifier is case-sensitive) and alias the value as `PostulationDetail_status` (again, case-sensitive).

Comment: Tested with single quotes and i got a different error:

``
[Nest] 10968  - 18-11-2021 12:44:26   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
QueryFailedError: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
``

Comment: @LuisContreras We can't help with that unless we can see the entire query.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the question

Comment: @LuisContreras - no, DON'T edit the question, ask a separate one (in a new thread). The new question is very unlikely to be related to the current one (that has already been answered).

Comment: I review the ouput sql on oracle and found the error. thanks, you solved me the problem.